# How to write a function that takes a list of column names of a dataframe and orders the df by that list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I'd like to build a function (spark, scala) that takes a predefined list of columns and then sorts the dataframe depending on the columns from that list

```
def orderColumns(df: DataFrame, columns: Array[String]): DataFrame = { ...
```

There are keys defined for all the dataframes and they are used as common keys between 2 dataframes in order to compare them. But what I need now is to sort the dataframes using those keys. There are different keys defined, their names and number are different, so I cannot use their hardcoded names.

The following code would work just fine, but I cannot use hardcoded values.

```
   val list = List($"col1", $"col2")
   df.orderBy(list: _*)
```

Comment: Use `col("nameOfCol")`? Rather than `$"col"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `list` variable is a `List[Column]`, so you just need to turn your `Array[String]` into a `List[Column]` and then you can use the code that you already created:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def orderColumns(df: DataFrame, columns: Array[String]): DataFrame = {
  val columnsList = columns.map(df.col(_))
  df.orderBy(columnsList: _*)
}

val myDf = Seq(
  (1, 1, 5),
  (6, 2, 3),
  (9, 1, 4),
  (6, 3, 2)
).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")

scala> orderColumns(myDf, Array("col1", "col2")).show
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   1|   5|
|   6|   2|   3|
|   6|   3|   2|
|   9|   1|   4|
+----+----+----+


scala> orderColumns(myDf, Array("col1", "col3")).show
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   1|   5|
|   6|   3|   2|
|   6|   2|   3|
|   9|   1|   4|
+----+----+----+
```